How do I fix browser tabs keep switching in Tosca? Handling multiple tabs in Tosca
I have two tabs with same tab name and functions, I have used ContraintIndex to steer the elements between each tabs, even though it switches to the first tab before each action in tab 2. Sometimes it keeps switching like in a loop.
It would be really helpful about any suggestions. Is there an better way to handle multiple tabs in browser?
I tried using "ContraintIndex" to select the correct elements between tab 1 and tab 2, but it didn't work.

Try giving tbox wait in between your different actions. ContraintIndex should work in this case.
